# Como incluir decimal em condição no PHP

Tags: php

Estou pegando um valor de um formulário que vem assim:

> 1222,22 (sem ponto no milhar, apenas com a `,` no decimal)

Então estou criando uma condição, assim:

```
if ($var1 < 1111,11) {
    $var2 = 1;
}
elseif ($var1 > 1111,11 && $var1 < 9999,99) {
    $var2 = 2;
}
else {
    $var2 = 3;
```

Mas não está dá certo, parece que a `,` não é aceita ali na condição... Tentei também como string (colocando os números entre aspas), e assim já aceita, mas também não resolveu.

Comment: Acho que você pode usar ou round(), ele tem uma condição bacana... mas normalmente não uso `,` pra decimal.. uso `.`...

Comment: Já tentei com o `.`, mas como recebo com `,` não deu certo... não entendi o que vc quis dizer com usar `round()`, se o que quero é justamente considerar as casa decimais... p.ex., se o valor entrado for `1111,12`, então `$var2 = 2`.

Comment: Mas pra você conseguir verificar, você terá que então formatar a numeração vinda, você pode usar o number_format(), pra atualizar a variavel, tornando-a com ponto, e ai elaborar a comparação.

Comment: @AndréBaill Ah entendi, funcionou assim: `if (number_format($var1, 2, ".", "") < 1111.11)` etc... Coloca como resposta. Valeu!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tente desta forma, veja se ajuda...

```
$var_a = "1111.1";
$var_b = NULL;

if($var_a <= "1111.1"){
     $var_b = 1;
} elseif($var_a >= "1111.1" || $var_a >= "9999.99"){
     $var_b = 2;
}

return $var_b;
```

## Alteração

```
$var_a = numbert_format("1111,1", 2, ",", ".");
$var_b = NULL;

if($var_a <= numbert_format("1111,1", 2, ",", ".")){
     $var_b = 1;
} elseif($var_a >= numbert_format("1111,1", 2, ",", ".") || $var_a >= numbert_format("9999,9", 2, ",", ".")){
     $var_b = 2;
}

return $var_b;
```

Comment: Como vc mesmo sugeriu, funcionou com `number_format`... acho que esta resposta que vc postou não está totalmente adequada, porque a entrada é com `,`...

Comment: Eu dei +1, mas acho que seria legal se você atualizasse com o `number_format` etc...

Comment: Resposta Atualizada.

Comment: Então, aqui eu to usando uma máscara de entrada pra esse número `function formatFromMaskMoney($value) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9.]+[,]( |)\d{2}$/', $value) !== 0) {
        $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
        $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    }
    return $value;
}` e acho que por isso funcionou com number_format... dá uma olhada nos comentários da resposta do Joerison....

Answer (score 4):

Eu não entendi bem o que você quer, mas acredito que você pode usar `str_replace` ou `strtr`, por exemplo:

```
function normalizarFloat($numero) {
    if (strpos($numero, ',') !== false) {
        $data = trim($data, ',');//Remove virgula do fim e do começo - só por segurança
        $data = str_replace(',', '.', $numero);//Transforma , em .

        $total = count(explode('.', $data));

        if ($total > 2) {
            //Evita que o script continue a executar acaso seja adicionado algum valor que não pode ser convertido
            throw new Exception($numero . ' não pode ser convertido');
        }

        return (double) $data;
    } else if (is_numeric($numero)) {
        return $numero;
    }

    //Entrada invalida
    throw new Exception($numero . ' é uma entrada invalida');

}
```

Usando:

```
if ($var1 < normalizarFloat('1111,11')) {
    $var2 = 1;
}
elseif ($var1 > normalizarFloat('1111,11') && $var1 < normalizarFloat('9999,99')) {
    $var2 = 2;
} else {
    $var2 = 3;
}
```

Comment: Então, com `number_format` deu certo. Com a função parece mais elegante, mas eu já to usando `empty` na entrada do número, e o campo não aceita letras... será que seria melhor usar a função pra evitar que o script continue rodando caso não seja possível converter? valeu +1

Comment: @gustavox você pode remover a fork do is_numeric. A ideia é apenas evitar que dados como `,109009` causem erros de numeros flutuantes, que geraria `0.109009` ao invés de `109009` e também forçar o Exception para não haver execução do script com dados inválidos.

Comment: Não entendi o que significa "remover a fork do is_numeric" (lembre-se de que sou novato :-) ), mas entendi agora o que queres evitar... mas acho que não precisa mesmo, porque o campo de entrada não aceita nada além de números (0-9)... valeu mesmo, abraços.

Comment: @gustavox desculpe usei o termo errado, remover a `if` que contém `is_numeric`. Lembre-se se o sistema trás dados do front-end ele pode ser burlado, segurança em primeiro lugar \O/

Comment: Nossa, ainda não entendi, e agora fiquei com medo! rsrs Eu to usando essa máscara pra transformar a entrada: `function formatFromMaskMoney($value) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9.]+[,]( |)\d{2}$/', $value) !== 0) {
        $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
        $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    }
    return $value;
}`

Comment: O valor de value vem de um `$_POST` ou `$_GET`? @gustavox

Comment: De um $_POST... é que no campo de entrada do form uso o mask_money, e quando chega no php, uso aquela máscara, daí usando o number_format deu certo pra fazer a condição... Tem algum risco usar assim? Valeu.

Comment: Requisições PHP podem ser manipiladas, o javascript pode falhar e o usuário digitar qualquer coisas aletoria por erro então será enviado dados sem a formatação do `mask_money`

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar função **str_replace**, veja:

```
$var1 = "1111,2";
$source = array(',');
$replace = array('.');
$var1 = str_replace($source, $replace, $var1);

if ($var1 < 1111.11) {
    $var2 = 1;
}
elseif ($var1 > 1111.11 && $var1 < 9999.99) {
    $var2 = 2;
}
else {
    $var2 = 3;
}
print $var2;
```

Comment: Ou também o number_format(), que tem a mesma função para tratar numeração e decimais. Funcionaria também... Boa solução a sua!

Comment: Aqui number_format zerou a parte decimal, nesse exemplo logo abaixo a saída foi 1111.00, sendo que deveria ter sido 1111,25. EXEMPLO:
$var1 = "1111,25";
$var1 = number_format($var1, 2, '.', '');

Comment: +1 Boa solução, mas ainda to achando melhor com `number_format` (mais simples, menos código...).

Comment: Mas igual eu falei, usando aqui `number_format` ele zera a parte decimal, aí não aconteceu o mesmo? Obrigado.

Comment: @JoerisonSilva aqui funcionou, não entendi direito seu exemplo...

Comment: `$var1 = "1112,25";`
    `$var1 = number_format($var1, 2, '.', '');`
    `print $var1;`

Comment: Ah, então, acho que aqui funciona assim porque to usando esta máscara de entrada: `function formatFromMaskMoney($value) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9.]+[,]( |)\d{2}$/', $value) !== 0) {
        $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
        $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    }
    return $value;
}`